# Fetching a game details of a particular game from Rawg Game API (https://rawg.io/apidocs)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, api, url

Has anyone ever worked with rawg game API (https://rawg.io/apidocs), if so how to access particular game details with API key included?

```
https://api.rawg.io/api/games?key=MY_API_KEY&id=558980
```

I have tried the above API URL but it does not give me the game details. It response with some different stuff not related to game details

Answer (score 1):

try this url it will work : `https://api.rawg.io/api/games/id?key=MY_API_KEY`
and remember to replace the id directly with it's number.